# VBA script, need to get the file name and hardcode the sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I tried with the changes as below code

```
    Dim SourceFolder As String
    Dim FileExt As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wsSource1 As Worksheet, wsSource2 As Worksheet, wsSource3 As Worksheet, wsSource4 As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim DestRow As Long

    ' Set the source folder path and file extension
    SourceFolder = "C:\TEST_1\"
    FileExt = "*.xlsx" ' Change to your file extension

    ' Set the destination worksheet
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ConsolidatedData") ' Change to your destination sheet name

    ' Clear existing data in the destination sheet
    wsDest.Cells.Clear

    ' Initialize destination row
    DestRow = 2

    ' Loop through each file in the folder
    FileName = Dir(SourceFolder & FileExt)
    Do While FileName <> ""
        Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(SourceFolder & FileName, ReadOnly:=True)

        ' Set references to source worksheets
        Set wsSource1 = wbSource.Sheets("Monthly1") ' Change to your sheet names
        Set wsSource2 = wbSource.Sheets("Monthly2")
        Set wsSource3 = wbSource.Sheets("Monthly3")
        Set wsSource4 = wbSource.Sheets("Monthly4")

        ' Copy data from source sheets to destination sheet
        Dim LastRowSrc1 As Long
        Dim LastRowSrc2 As Long
        Dim LastRowSrc3 As Long
        Dim LastRowSrc4 As Long
        
        LastRowSrc1 = wsSource1.Cells(wsSource1.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        LastRowSrc2 = wsSource2.Cells(wsSource2.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        LastRowSrc3 = wsSource3.Cells(wsSource3.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        LastRowSrc4 = wsSource4.Cells(wsSource4.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        
        wsSource1.Range("B4:O30").Copy
        wsDest.Range("C" & DestRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        wsDest.Range("A" & DestRow, "A" & DestRow + LastRowSrc1 - 4).Value = FileName
        wsDest.Range("B" & DestRow, "B" & DestRow + LastRowSrc1 - 4).Value = wsSource1.Name
        DestRow = DestRow + LastRowSrc1 - 3

        wsSource2.Range("B4:O30").Copy
        wsDest.Range("C" & DestRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        wsDest.Range("A" & DestRow, "A" & DestRow + LastRowSrc2 - 4).Value = FileName
        wsDest.Range("B" & DestRow, "B" & DestRow + LastRowSrc2 - 4).Value = wsSource2.Name
        DestRow = DestRow + LastRowSrc2 - 3

        wsSource3.Range("B4:O29").Copy
        wsDest.Range("C" & DestRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        wsDest.Range("A" & DestRow, "A" & DestRow + LastRowSrc3 - 4).Value = FileName
        wsDest.Range("B" & DestRow, "B" & DestRow + LastRowSrc3 - 4).Value = wsSource3.Name
        DestRow = DestRow + LastRowSrc3 - 3

        wsSource4.Range("B4:O25").Copy
        wsDest.Range("C" & DestRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        wsDest.Range("A" & DestRow, "A" & DestRow + LastRowSrc4 - 4).Value = FileName
        wsDest.Range("B" & DestRow, "B" & DestRow + LastRowSrc4 - 4).Value = wsSource4.Name
        DestRow = DestRow + LastRowSrc4 - 3
        
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
        FileName = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

This code Generates VBA code to loop thru multiple excel files, copy data from 4 sheets into one sheet, each sheet having specific range to select and consolidate all into one sheet. copies only the values and ignore all formats & formulas
I have made the changes,
Filename and the sheetname is coming in the output, it has to populate for all the values, any help please..

Thanks,

Comment: `wsDest.Cells(LastRow + 2, 5).Value = SourceSheet.Name` perhaps. How/where is LastRow set.

Comment: Dim LastRow As Long
wsDest.Cells(LastRow + 2, 5).Value = FileName
wsDest.Cells(LastRow + 2, 6).Value = SourceSheet

I have added the above code, but nothing is coming in output.

Comment: Update your answer to show where you added the code. You are writing to Column E but `wsDest.Range("A" & wsDest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 2)` is pasting below the last non-blank cell in Column A.

Answer (score 2):

To place filenames and sheet names vertically in column E, update the column reference as needed.

The `wsSource1.UsedRange.Copy` is unnecessary and will be overwritten by the next line, so can be removed.

The `arrConf` array stores sheet name and data range pairs as configuration metadata. You can add more sheets or modify ranges without impacting other logic.

```vb
    FileName = Dir(SourceFolder & FileExt)
    Do While FileName <> ""
        Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(SourceFolder & FileName, ReadOnly:=True)
        Dim arrConf, lastRow As Long
        arrConf = Array(Array("Monthly_1", "Monthly_2", "Monthly_3", "Monthly_4"), _
                        Array("B4:O30", "B4:O30", "B4:O29", "B4:O25"))
        For j = 0 To UBound(arrConf(0))
            lastRow = wsDest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            wsDest.Cells(lastRow + 1, 5).Value = FileName
            wsDest.Cells(lastRow + 2, 5).Value = arrConf(0)(j)
            Set wsSource1 = wbSource.Sheets(arrConf(0)(j))
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            wsSource1.Range(arrConf(1)(j)).Copy
            wsDest.Range("A" & lastRow + 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Next
        wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
        FileName = Dir
    Loop
```

---

> Question:  Output is expected as File_Name Monthly_1 Values1 File_Name Monthly_1 Values2 File_Name Monthly_1 Values3

> Answer: Using `Range().Value =` is more efficient than copy / pastespecial.

```
    ' Copy data from source sheets to destination sheet
    DestRow = 1
    Dim rSrc As Range, rCol As Range, iCol As Integer, iRowCnt As Integer
    Set rSrc = wsSource1.Range("B4:O30")
    iRowCnt = rSrc.Rows.Count
    iCol = 1
    For Each rCol In rSrc.Columns
        wsDest.Cells(DestRow, iCol).Value = Filename
        wsDest.Cells(DestRow, iCol + 1).Value = wsSource1.Name
        wsDest.Cells(DestRow, iCol + 2).Resize(iRowCnt, 1) = rCol.Value
        iCol = iCol + 3
    Next
    DestRow = DestRow + 27
```

Comment: Set wsSource1 = wbSource.Sheets(arrConf(0)(j)) --in this line it gives the error subscript out of range

Comment: Please make sure the worksheets' name are correct. `Array("Monthly_1", "Monthly_2", "Monthly_3", "Monthly_4")` I just copied it from OP.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply, the file name and sheet name coming at the end, is it possible to get vertically for all the columns

Comment: You can paste before write file name and sheet name into work sheet. Please provide the detail about ``vertically` in OP.

Comment: I have updated the code and getting the below results.

Output is coming as below.
File_Name  Monthly_1  Values1
        Values2
        Values3

Output is expected as 
File_Name  Monthly_1  Values1
File_Name  Monthly_1  Values2
File_Name  Monthly_1  Values3

What changes needs to be done, can somebody help please.
Thanks,